# Is there a way, I can empty the whole JSONObject -- java

Tags: java, json

I have to populate a json object like this, let say it is named detailJSON:

```
{"amount": "5.00", "ac_no": "123456" }
```

I do it this way:

```
detailJSON.put("amount","5.00");
detailJSON.put("ac_no","123456");
```

After this, the detail is entered in some shared preferences, and now I want to **clear** this JSONObject and use the same detailJSON object to store another json (with different keys), this way:

```
{"amount":"6.00", "loan_no":"123456"}
```

I know there is a method, remove(), that removes the particular key and corresponding value.

**This works**:

```
detailJSON.remove("amount");
detailJSON.remove("ac_no");
```

and then use it --

```
detailJSON.put("amount","6.0");
detailJSON.put("loan_no","123456");
```

Now this is a very simple example. In the code I'm working on, I have a lot of keys, so using remove actually increases the LOC. Also, each time before removing I need to check whether JSONObject `has` that particular key or not.

Is there any other way, I can implement clearing of the JSONObject??

I tried

```
detailJSON=null ;
detailJSON=new JSONObject();
```

But it does not work.

I am basically in search of something like clear() method, if exists.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that? Why not use a fresh JSONObject every time? I think it would be more costly to remove every single field than just creating a new one.

Comment: @UweAllner I too totally agree with you but this is the business constraint, to maintain such a structure.

Comment: `detailJSON=new JSONObject();` should work. You seem to have a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: `detailJSON=null;` must remove the reference to actual object `detailJSON=new JSONObject();` must point to newly created object. Ater creating new object, populate with new values and check whether this works or not.

Comment: okay, this should have worked, but thing is like this. I'm passing the detailJSON to the function, where this work is done, so here if I create the new json object it is the local variable, hence it does not work. Whereas remove work on the original reference.

Comment: In that case, simply return the changed json from your function and set it equal to the value returned

Comment: detailJSON=new JSONObject("{}");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Iterator keys = detailJSON.keys();
while(keys.hasNext())
  detailJSON.remove((String)detailJSON.keys().next());
```

Comment: This is giving compilation error -- 
`Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` in the line detailJSON.keys(). detailJSON is an instance of JSONObject.

Comment: Well after you edited, this works, I had to cast to String though -- 
`detailJSON.remove((String)detailJSON.keys().next());`

Comment: But it's basically the same as `detailJSON.remove("amount");` even worse, it will creates `Iterator` twice per loop. First to determine is there are any more elements, and after that, to get the next element.

Comment: this will throw ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 5):

this version has an overhead because of getting the key-set everytime, but it works without concurrent modification exception.

```
while(json.length()>0)
   json.remove(json.keys().next());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could, but it will be a hack.

```
Iterator i = detailJSON.keys();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    i.next().remove();
}

//or

detailJSON.keySet().clear();
```

It works, because `JSONObject.keySet()` will return you `this.map.keySet()`. And what JavaDoc for `HashMap.keySet()` said:

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

Java's `HashMap` from collections will return you `java.util.HashMap.KeySet` and `java.util.HashMap.KeySet.clear();` just calls `map.clear()` (KeySet is an inner class of java.util.HashMap)

Comment: `detailJSON.keySet().clear();` does not work, it gives this compilation error -- `
The method keySet() is undefined for the type JSONObject`. Trying the first solution now

Comment: The first one also gives an error, to add the type cast to iterator, having done that, it gives run time error.

Comment: Whch JSONObject do you use. I've tested this approach with snippet http://pastebin.com/SBDR3iaB

Comment: Here is what I've used `org.json.JSONObject.keySet()` http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20141113/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.keySet%28%29

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method

```
public HashMap clearMap(HashMap detailJSON){
  for(String key: detailJSON.keySet())
    detailJSON.remove(key);
  return detailJSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `detailJSON` is an map variable, the you can use `detailJSON.clear()` method to empty values in the map.

Comment: it is JSONObject variable.

Comment: then detailJSON = new JSONObject() should remove all your previous data and will put and empty detailJSON object for you

Comment: `detailJSON = new JSONObject()` would not work if `detailJSON` is declared as `final`, so that comment only refers to a specific usecase.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no clear method for `JSONObject` :. if you have to iterate all the `JSONObject` to clear it, better you get the parent node, and update with a `new JSONObject()`.

You probably using `while` to get those details, so you can do this:

```
Iterator keys = mJson.keys();
while(keys.hasNext())
{
    String key = keys.next();
    JSONObject detailJSON = mJson.getJSONObject(key);
    JSONObject newDetail = new JSONObject();
    ...
    mJson.put(key,newDetail);
}
```

And when using `JSONArray`:

```
for (int i=0; i < mJson.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject detailJSON = mJson.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject newDetail = new JSONObject();
    ...
    mJson.put(i,newDetail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### ConcurrentModificationException Proof

Directly using key set iterator of a `JSONObject` inside a loop for removing items will cause throw **ConcurrentModificationException**.
This is because when you remove an element, the `JSONObject` automatically modifies its key set that you are using inside the loop at the moment. And this's a violation!

One solution is to copy keys to an array first, then use the array instead of the iterator itself, like below :

```
public static void clearJson(JSONObject json) {
    if (json.length() > 0) {
        String[] keysArr = new String[json.length()];

        int counter = 0;
        for (Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();iter.hasNext();)
            keysArr[counter++] = iter.next();

        for (String key : keysArr)
            json.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could re-declare the variable

```
JSONObject detailJSON= new JSONObject();

detailJSON.put("amount","5.00");
detailJSON.put("ac_no","123456");

detailJSON = new JSONObject()
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean re _assign_?